# Render an image in SurfaceImageSource with direct2D

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, bitmapimage, direct2d

I'm making a Windows Store Application that display really big images in a ScrollViewer.
The source image is very big and the rendering with the Image is bad (because the Image is really smaller than the source image, so the scaling make the result ugly).

I want to use direct2D to have a better rendering (the project is in c#).
I'm really new to this, so I don't really know how to do... I've found those links that seems interesting:

- [XAML SurfaceImageSource DirectX interop sample (Windows 8.1)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SurfaceImageSource-58f7e4d5)
- [How to Draw a BitmapSource Using Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The SurfaceImageSource sample is good, but only shows how to render sharpes...
And I don't know how to use the second links with SurfaceImageSource.

Is there anybody who have a good example about this? Thanks!

Comment: Check out [SharpDX's Managed Direct2D library](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/n-sharpdx-direct2d1). It's pretty straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [VirtualSurfaceImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx).It can render large image.
Learn more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx